# How to troubleshoot SQL "The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to troubleshoot a timeout issue that occurs on one of our SQL 2005 servers.

The database responds normally for about a day until we  start to see sql timeout errors.  After that all queries take 30+ seconds to return and it does not return to normal operation until we reset the SQL services. The sql queries are very simple, updating a single row in a database.

It seems like the problem is specific to one database because we can run the same queries on another database on the same server and they return normally. I've looked into possible locks using the technique outlined [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/write-your-own-splock-system-stored-procedure-in-sql-server-2005/267) and I don't see anything that sticks out.  This is on one of our beta servers so there are very few requests to it.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: See [Waits and Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up rebuilding the database from script and the problem went away.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer with us even if it was "one of those"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried polling for dbcc opentran? It could be you have an uncommitted transaction problem occurring on that database. Also, worth checking the collation of the databases is the same, always the first thing to check in a "this one works this one dosent" scenario

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182792.aspx